# Adding address to article

Tags: addresses

I'm using this [template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/deedy-resume-cv), and editing it on writeLaTeX. I'd like to add my address to the title section underneath my email and phone number. I've tried using "\address", but this produces this message: `Undefined control sequence. l.35 \address {Test address}`.

I've also tried modifying the "namesection" part of the class file without any luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This template does not define a separate command for address in the title. The same applies to the phone number, as in their example they have added manually themselves. You can do the same. Simply add your address by appending `\\ Your address` to the `\namesection`:

```
\namesection{Debarghya}{Das}{ % Your name
\urlstyle{same}\url{http://debarghyadas.com} \\ % Your website, LinkedIn profile or other web address
\href{mailto:dd367@cornell.edu}{dd367@cornell.edu} | 607.379.5733 \\Your address goes here!% Your contact information
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just define an `\address` command and use that in `\namesection`

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{deedy-resume} % Use US Letter paper, change to a4paper for A4 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\address}{John Doe, Carnegie Street 150, Somewhere on this planet}

\begin{document}

\lastupdated % Print the Last Updated text at the top right

\namesection{Doe}{Doe}{ % Your name
\address

}



\section{Introduction}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]